# Запустить анимацию при прокрутке страницы

Tags: javascript

Есть следующий код:

```js
function startAnimation() {
    var box = document.querySelector('.box');
    var boxPosition = box.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var screenPosition = window.innerHeight / 1.2;

    if(boxPosition < screenPosition) {
        box.classList.add('animation');
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', startAnimation);
```

```css
@keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}

.box.animation {
    animation: rotate 1s ease-in 0.1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.container {
  background-color: #03A9F4;
  height: 2000px;
} 

.box-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 490px;
  border: 5px solid #FFEB3B;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #8BC34A;
  border: 5px solid #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    
  </div>
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div> 
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы каждый .box поворачивался когда он появляется на экране?
Я понимаю, что все .box нужно положить в массив, но что делать дальше с массивом я не представляю...

Comment: есть готовые библиотеки типа wow.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение оказалось проще, чем я думал) 

`querySelector` находит только первый указанный элемент на странице. Чтобы найти все, нужно использовать `querySelectorAll()`. А он и так уже возвращает "почти" массив

(демо):

```js
var test = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

console.log( test[0] );
console.log( test[1] );
console.log( test[2] );
console.log( test[3] );
console.log( test );
```

```html
<div class="box">0000</div>
<div class="box">1111</div>
<div class="box">2222</div>
<div class="box">3333</div>
```

А в вашем случае, элементы box как созданы - так и остаются на месте. Поэтому можно каждый раз не пересоздавать переменную внутри функции, а вынести её за её пределы.

```js
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

function startAnimation() {
  var pos = window.innerHeight / 1.2;
  var i, boxtop;
  for(i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
    boxtop = box[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if(boxtop < pos ) {
        box[i].classList.add('animation');
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', startAnimation);
```

```css
@keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}

.box.animation {
    animation: rotate 1s ease-in 0.1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.container {
  background-color: #03A9F4;
  height: 2000px;
} 

.box-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 490px;
  border: 5px solid #FFEB3B;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #8BC34A;
  border: 5px solid #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-wrapper"></div>
  
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div> 
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Демо работы `for()`

```js
var i;

for( i = 5; i < 10; i++ ){
  console.log( 'На этом круге [i] равен - ' + i );
}

/*Это то же самое, что и

console.log( 5 );
console.log( 6 );
console.log( 7 );
console.log( 8 );
console.log( 9 );

for просто сильно сокращает код. Вместо i < 10 в вашем случае используется
количество элементов box. А i++ просто частный случай. То же, что и i = i + 1. 
Там может быть вообще всё что угодно.
*/
```

P.s. хорошо бы отключить функцию после выполнения всех анимаций... чтобы оно не продолжало проверять столько всего при каждом скролле. Но пока не знаю как)